# Getting tabulars to line up in the end of two columns

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

In the following document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{|c|}\hline test\\\hline\end{tabular*}

\vfill

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{|c|}\hline test\\\hline\end{tabular*}

\pagebreak

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{|c|}\hline test\\\hline\end{tabular*}

\vfill

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{|c|}\hline test\\\hline\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the second and fourth tabulars to be lined up, however the fourth one is placed a little higher, as if LaTeX inserts some space after it. If I put some text instead of the tabulars, it lines up perfectly. How can I make it work with tabulars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\newpage` instead of `\pagebreak`: This also makes the lower left tabular move up, so that you have your desired alignment. Usually `\newpage` is not recommended, but as you have some `\vfill` in between, this is no problem here.

EDIT:

Here's a partial explanation of what happens. Your tabular produces an hbox with a depth of 3.9pt. This is the 3.9pt that also TH talked about. Now suppose you have a bottom margin of 1cm. Then it is *not* the very bottom of the text that is 1cm from the bottom of the page, but the *baseline* of the last hbox of the page/column. Thus, if the last line has decenders, such as the letter "j" has, then the descenders will be a little closer to the bottom of the page than you might expect. This is intended design since it makes the *baselines* of the last lines of the pages align.

In your case, the lower horizontal line of the tabular is the "descender", as far as I understand, and it descends 3.9pt as mentioned above. Now the `article` class with 10pt fontsize defines a `maxdepth` of 5pt, which essentially means that you can't get more than 5pt closer than expected to the bottom of the page. The 3.9pt of the tabular are less than 5pt, so this will be accepted.

Now you'll ask: Why doesn't the same thing apply to the second column? This I can't fully explain, but I can describe what happens. The `\end{document}` at the end calls the macro `\clearpage`, which in turn calls `\newpage`. This is the reason why you get the desired alignment if you use `\newpage` instead of `\pagebreak` as I propose above: For both columns you then have the same macro ending the column.

And why does `\newpage` prevent the 3.9pt "descender"? The `\newpage` macro adds a `\vfil` before the `\penalty-10000` that causes the pagebreak, this `\vfil` gives another permissible breakpoint, and here you don't have any descenders. Finally, `\vfil` is an infinitely stretchable glue, but it's infinitely weaker than `\vfill`, so it doesn't prevent the last tabular from moving to the bottom of the text. Just try it yourself and replace both occurences of `\vfill` in the document with `\vfil`!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't very satisfying. I'm not sure why this happens. If you add a `\pagebreak` after the last tabular, they line up. There is something about `\penalty-10000` (which is basically what `\pagebreak` does) that causes it to work as you think it should.

If you look at the boxes that result from the page builder, the left column has an additional glue of -3.9 pt which is what is causing it to be lower. I'm not sure where that is coming from exactly (although I'm sure someone can explain it).

Here's an experiment you can try to see this yourself. Add `\nointerlineskip\null` after the second tabular with no other changes. This causes the tabular to move up (it gets rid of the -3.9 pt of glue). Now, add `\pagebreak` after the fourth tabular and notice how the left column is now the one that is 3.9 points too high.

Comment: Thanks, that allows me to do what I want. My guess is that the left column is too low, as after setting margins to 1cm with geometry it seems to be closer than that to the margin. (I may be wrong, I'm comparing it with the top margin without printing.)
Now lets wait until someone with more experience explains what causes this behavior.