# Problem with layout after including pictures

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, wrapfigure

I can't resolve the problem with including pictures. When I add a picture by using `\includegraphics` my text doesn't flush to the bottom (as it should) but it move up. It happens especially when I add `\wrapfigure` to the next side and footnote. Here you can see the text on the even page move a bit up. When I add \footnote it move up more. So, lines on the even and odd side don't match. [image]. 
[image]

And here is my minimal working preamble:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[
centering,
showframe,
papersize={160mm,235mm},
text={125mm,190.5mm},
]{geometry}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{14pt} 

\clubpenalty10000 
\widowpenalty10000 

\sloppy 

\frenchspacing

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
```

I thought maybe `\flushbottom` would help but didn't (maybe because of `\parskip{0pt}`). I tried `\vspace` inside `{figure}` environment but it didn't work too. I found maybe this would help

```
 \setlength\floatsep{12pt plus 12pt minus 2pt}
```

but wouldn't. Do you know what to do?
Thanks for any help.

Sorry for long post but I don't know how to use wrapfigure with lipsum. It is why I showed you only my preamble. I don't know how to put a picture at the top of the page (like on the odd page in my example). In this example text move up with wrapfigure on the next page and move a bit down without it whereas I need it exactly on the bottom line of the frame (When I don't include graphic the text is exactly on the line). Martin, I use {figure} as you can see below.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{venturis}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[
centering,
showframe,
papersize={160mm,235mm},
text={125mm,190.5mm},
]{geometry}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{14pt} 

\clubpenalty10000 
\widowpenalty10000 

\sloppy 

\frenchspacing

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \hspace{3pt}\fbox{\includegraphics[width=118mm]{photo.jpg}}
    %\vspace{-10pt}
    \caption*{\footnotesize\centering{lorem}}
 \end{figure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam fermentum, purus eget ultrices consectetur, odio magna commodo metus, sed blandit ipsum nisl at mi. Maecenas et sapien sapien. Proin quis arcu vel nulla commodo elementum. Fusce id ultrices enim. Aenean quis suscipit quam. Etiam egestas, felis et lobortis auctor, felis felis porttitor nibh, quis placerat quam est hendrerit purus. Nam luctus tincidunt turpis, at bibendum risus semper vitae. Praesent quis tortor sit amet massa aliquam sollicitudin. Curabitur venenatis tempus ligula elementum semper. Maecenas vehicula urna in lectus varius non dignissim felis elementum. Praesent dignissim ultricies massa at faucibus. Nam sed libero enim. Sed euismod mollis tortor, sit amet elementum nulla lacinia ut.

Nullam congue turpis sed arcu mollis sit amet vulputate sapien iaculis. Aliquam eget nulla enim. Praesent pulvinar felis ut risus laoreet suscipit. Nulla id velit purus. In nec est ut ligula pulvinar congue eu id massa. Donec id porta est. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce a dapibus tellus. Phasellus auctor nisi arcu. Proin libero quam, fringilla vitae hendrerit ut, fermentum in lectus. Nulla tempus sem dolor, posuere aliquet velit. In lacus nisl, porttitor euismod lobortis id, blandit id nulla. Vestibulum tristique nunc et eros fringilla pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce dignissim, sapien ac feugiat aliquam, nunc nisl imperdiet dui, quis volutpat massa nisl sed lectus.

Suspendisse imperdiet feugiat tempor. Vivamus tincidunt justo laoreet urna vestibulum aliquet. Mauris sed varius dui. Donec tempus ipsum non dolor euismod id molestie ante condimentum. Nulla vehicula, erat quis accumsan luctus, lorem ligula viverra sem, sit amet laoreet mi mauris non diam. Maecenas augue dui, tincidunt non lacinia vitae, lacinia at quam. Donec dapibus auctor nunc. Proin aliquet sollicitudin luctus. Maecenas sed mi odio. Sed elementum massa sed nisl pulvinar eu iaculis ligula ornare. Sed at pulvinar lorem. Curabitur ac quam sit amet erat ullamcorper ornare. Vestibulum eu tempor lacus. Donec ultrices, sapien vel gravida hendrerit, lorem lacus eleifend ipsum, in tristique justo velit ac tellus. Quisque vestibulum fringilla arcu posuere ultricies. In placerat imperdiet scelerisque. Morbi quis dui vitae neque cursus rutrum vel semper ante. Donec at orci sed nisl iaculis cursus non tempor lorem. Duis eget risus augue, eget viverra felis.

Nulla justo diam, posuere ut egestas non, varius facilisis enim. Donec suscipit, dolor nec lobortis ornare, velit erat interdum tellus, ac elementum orci mauris vitae magna. \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
%\vspace{-10pt}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{photo.jpg}}
\vspace{-22pt} 
\caption*{\footnotesize\centering{lorem}}
\end{wrapfigure}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus dui dolor. Quisque ut felis dolor. Aliquam aliquam venenatis leo sed vehicula. Praesent neque justo, facilisis non gravida et, feugiat nec ante. Donec tincidunt, sem sit amet elementum commodo, felis tellus volutpat metus, quis ultrices mi urna et tellus. Ut sit amet scelerisque elit. Aliquam ac magna id lacus accumsan consequat et eu nunc. Nam lorem leo, mattis aliquet congue ultrices, pharetra in nisl. Curabitur cursus neque nec eros pulvinar aliquet.

Pellentesque vestibulum adipiscing dapibus. Donec auctor, dolor a viverra auctor, tellus urna cursus nulla, et imperdiet mauris mauris in arcu. Quisque condimentum, quam eu mollis bibendum, erat augue viverra augue, eu viverra magna sapien in felis. Aliquam scelerisque tempus quam, adipiscing posuere lectus dictum et. Integer feugiat viverra egestas. Cras malesuada dictum felis, eu aliquam erat bibendum vitae. Curabitur ac metus non lorem hendrerit ornare eget eget nisl. Vestibulum ante ante, lobortis eu congue sed, euismod in risus. Sed viverra ornare dui, et condimentum libero pellentesque at. Sed congue est ut purus ornare euismod. Vivamus venenatis dui sit amet magna dignissim suscipit. Nunc eu nunc eu nulla semper auctor. Mauris lacus felis, facilisis tincidunt fermentum a, cursus nec enim. Proin eu placerat libero. Praesent sagittis, lectus ac ultricies ultrices, nulla ante imperdiet risus, molestie porta erat mauris a dui. Quisque consequat lorem ut sem faucibus rutrum.


\end{document}
```

Comment: @kotspot: Please provide a full minimal example, not just the preamble. You can use the `lipsum` or `blindtext` package to insert dummy text. Are you using a `figure` float for the image or some non-floating environment? I don't think it is caused by `\includegraphics`.

Comment: There is also a related question about [line misalignment with multiple columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11007/2975), which isn't really answered yet.

Comment: @kotspot: Please do provide a full compilable example, as suggested by Martin. It _might_ be a problem with descenders and the `maxdepth` as described in [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/gettting-tabulars-to-line-up-in-the-end-of-two-columns/4301#4301), but that's impossible to tell without a full example.

Comment: @Hendrik: I just did, but I'm not sure how to apply it here. Please note that this issue does also appear with `book` class and just `lipsum` text and some `figure`. The baselines on both sides do not align. Maybe forcing the image to by `n\baselineskip` high will fix it?

Comment: Hendrik, I've just used \pagebreak just before \begin{wrapfigure}. Now text isn't above the line but it's a few pt under it.

Comment: Martin, I tried \baselineskip and it didn't work (but maybe I didn't use it correctly).

Comment: From what I have gathered, this is rather [hard to achieve in LaTeX, but might be easier in ConTeXt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/grid-system-in-latex/1479).

Comment: @kotspot: You need to add a `@` before the name of the user you want to address. Otherwise he/she isn't notified about the comment. It was just an idea with `\baselineskip`, I couldn't get it to work as well.

Comment: @kotspot: You wrote that you tried `\pagebreak`: To me it seems that this solves the problem; with `\pagebreak` before `\begin{wrapfigure}` the text on page 1 looks the same as when the `wrapfigure` is omitted. The _baseline_ of the text is sitting exactly on the line, and the descenders are, well, descending as they should. Please tell me if what I wrote makes sense to you.

Comment: @Hendrik, as I wrote yesterday the text is a bit below the line (on the page, where I have only the text, it is exactly on the line). Of course it looks better after using \pagebreak and I think now it's enough for me. I'm not a pedant but I'll try to find a solution in the future. And by the way, do you know why sometimes \pagebreak is treated like \\ (enter)? The last line on the page (just before using \pagebreak) is sometimes flushed to left. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kotspot: I can't see that the text is below the line, and if there's a pedant in the world, then it's me. Actually I can't see _any_ difference on the first page in the following two versions of your document: 1. the document with the `wrapfigure` completely removed, 2. the document with a `\pagebreak` _immediately_ after `magna.` (_No space_ after `magna.`!) Can you please tell me what you mean with "below the line"?

Comment: @Hendrik, you're right. Now \pagebreak works good. I really don't know how to explain it. Believe me it moved a bit down the line (that is generated by showframe in geometry package). The same is with \pagebreak that behaves like \\. Yesterday I had a problem and today it's ok. I had to mix something, but I don't know what. The most important is it works now. Sorry for confusion and thanks for help again! PS. By the way I had to change text height to 189.1mm to level lines on adjacent pages.

Comment: @kotspot: OK, great, thanks. I'll add an actual answer soon.

Comment: @Hendrik, I think I've just discovered what happened with \pagebreak as \\. When I put \pagebreak like that: "word\pagebreak \begin{wrapfigure}" everything is ok, but when I use this: "word \pagebreak \beign{wrapfigure}" last line (that ends with "word") flushes to left. It looks like no space should be between word and \pagebreak.

Comment: Eh, it isn't the end of problems. Problem appears again when I insert \footnote. Text on adjacent pages isn't in line again.

Comment: I had to set rigidly '\setlength{\skip\footins}{18pt}' to resolve it, but 18pt leaves a big gap between text and footnotes. I can use 4pt, but it's too small. I'm totaly beginner in desining layout, but I think it's a problem with general settings like textheight, ins't it? If so, what to do if I want to have the text flushed to the bottom (like in my example)? The only way is to use {grid} package or something else? Sorry for all that lamer's questions but I still don't know how LaTeX works. It looks for me very inflexible. Am I right or not?

Comment: @kotspot: Exactly, that's what I wrote, you mustn't leave space between `word` and `\pagebreak`. With footnotes it's a different story; I'm not sure what you're aiming at. To me, the footnote on your 2nd image looks exactly as it should; the footnote sits on the bottom line. You want it below that line?

Comment: @Hendrik, I hope I resolved my problem by using more "rubber" settings. I've changed a little the length of \skip\footins. Now I have in my preamble this: `\setlength{\skip\footins}{10pt plus 10pt minus 2pt}` and it seems to work good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, your first problem looks like a bug in `wrapfigure`. *Without* the `wrapfigure`, the last line of page 1 is nicely sitting on the line drawn by `showframe`; the descender of the "g" descends below that line as it should. *With* the `wrapfigure`, the descender of the "g" is sitting on the line drawn by `showframe`, which is indeed not desirable. A workaround is to put a `\pagebreak` immediately after the last word on page 1; in your example code this would be after `magna.`

Your second problem seems to be of a different nature, and it appears that you found some solution in the comments to the question `:-)`

Comment: I agree with blaming `wrapfigure`. In my tests `wrapfigure` behaved quite funny. Especially `{\begin{wrapfigure}...\end{wrapfigure}}` results in the figure being over placed over the text. (I'm already out of votes for today ...)

Comment: @kotsport: I just realized that I misspelled your user name all the time; somehow I didn't see the "r" - sorry!